# Terminal always opens with invalid bash script

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm not sure when or how I did this but every time I open up Terminal I see the following:

```
-bash: export: `/Users/derekcsm/Documents/ADT/sdk/platform-tools': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier
-bash: touch: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to clear this so that it doesn't happen every time?

Comment: Check your shell startup scripts (~/.bashrc etc)

Comment: Looks like someting is wrong with your `export PATH ...`

Comment: @CryHavok what am I looking for in there / where can I find that?

Comment: Similar: [Permission denied message everytime I start the Terminal](http://superuser.com/q/982515/87805)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal new window always shows -bash: Searching: command not found](http://superuser.com/questions/881261/terminal-new-window-always-shows-bash-searching-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely something is doing [`export $PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/not-a-valid-identifier-when-i-do-export-path), when what you want is `export PATH`. Check your [dotfiles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles) and any files [sourced](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) in them.